# How take all available space before meet a div with different dimension each time?

Tags: html, css, position

I have a div on the left that contains a name, and I don't know how much long this name can be. 
On the right I have another div containing some buttons. The number of them can change so I don't know how many buttons I have.

Using only css, how can I take all available space with the first div before meet the second?

I need having those 2 div always on one line.

**This is a final effect that I would have:**

http://www.clipular.com/c/5701413332058112.png?k=SiP2DmbxmooYIXxUlrAI6uP1OA0

Comment: Your best bet would be using a table rather than using two divisions, because in a table when row height increases, all cells in that row have their height's adjusted. You can style table cells similarly to divisions.

Comment: Could you add a sample of your code (HTML) to make the question clearer?

Answer (score 0):

Add some code you will get a better response.

It all depends how you are displaying.

If its a menu then with ul li a then just give them the attribute in css

Display :inline-block. This will render them in a line

Sorry just ré-read. Divs will be different.

You can do it with absolure positioning but i think you should throw some code on that you have tried for easy editing

Answer (score 0):

You can use display:table on the parent and display:table-cell on the children. Assign no widths and make them not wrap.

Here's a rough example:

#### https://jsbin.com/yibosi/1/edit?html,css,output

```
  <div>
    
    <div>first content</div>
    <div>second content</div>
    
  </div>
```

CSS

```
div {box-sizing:border-box;display:table;border:1px solid red;width:100%;}
div > div {border:0px;display:table-cell;white-space:nowrap}
```